# Show products based on IP address in Open Cart

Tags: opencart

I would like to display the products based on the area/region.
I have my site on open cart.
So I can do this with IP address or customers postal code number but I don't know how to do this so please help.

Comment: My opinion is to use area postal code to search result. On first screen add popup with enter postal area code textbox and submit button. His/her stored postal area stored to cookies/session and get result through his/her given area code result. I think it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize your efforts.
you need to create a custom module for your requirement.
or if you don't want to deep your head in customization you need to buy module something like this.

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=21013&filter_search=geo%20location